# How do deals happen between two countries at the very ground level?

Tags: international, trade

consider two countries, if one country is purchasing some goods from the another then how will that country is going to pay another country?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is common to talk in terms of trade between two countries and even use economic measures like balance of trade. It is not the state itself which is buying the goods (except as part of actual government procurement etc).

Of course in highly centralised economies significant portions of industry may be state owned or controlled which makes this distinction less clear and even in 'free-market' economies the state may retain some control of strategic and military exports. Conversely large corporations may have a significant influence on the government's negotiating position.

There are some cases where the government is more directly involved particularly in strategic assets like military hardware, mineral extraction, energy (especially nuclear) and other things like the financial sector and pharmaceuticals where licensing and regulation are more complex than for more ordinary commodities.

Similarity governments may offer incentives in terms of tax breaks or direct subsidies and may agree to modify regulatory structures and intellectual property and employment law to make a particular state or region more attractive. Although this also has to be balanced against domestic politics and and existing deals or trade bloc memberships.

What actually happens is that  companies based in the two countries with the deal will buy goods from each other, in some cases there may be specialist importers and exporters who act as middle-men but this doesn't make any fundamental difference.

What the respective governments agree is the legal terms in which trade is carried out. States have the right to control goods coming into and out of their borders and may impose tax and duties on some goods and impose restrictions on certain classes of goods eg weapons, hazardous materials, strategic resources and otherwise prohibited or controlled items.

From the economic perspective of the government, exports of goods represent money coming into the *economy* from outside, this revenue does not go directly to the state but is generally seen as beneficial for the economy as a whole.

A government may also impose taxes on goods entering or leaving the country, this revenue does go directly to the government but makes traded goods more expensive, so in a particular trade deal two countries may decide that it it better to have the general economic benefits of increased trade rather than the direct revenue from taxation.

There is also the consideration that import/export taxes place an administrative burden on both companies and the government in complying with and enforcing them eg consignments need to be documented and inspected to ensure that the correct taxes are paid.

There is also the issue of standards and regulation which are important in all sorts of areas including :

- consumer and environmental safety
- technical compatibility and interchangeability
- being able to specify an appropriate level of performance

For example if I buy a consignment of bolts from France I want to be sure that they will fit the socket set I bought from Germany.

The fundamental idea of trade deals is that they make trade between the countries involved easier and cheaper and the respective governments reap the benefits further down the line in terms of economic growth and the knock on effects of job creation and increased tax revenue.

Of course a trade deal doesn't guarantee this and it does potentially expose domestic industries to more competition but that ultimately comes down to the ability of the negotiators to strike a good deal.

Comment: What @SJuan76 said, although with a caveat that governments sometimes *can and do* trade directly (e.g. the government can act as a purchaser - for example of military hardware etc...; - OR, less frequently, as a producer; though the latter is more frequently the case through government-owned company such as Russia's or China's military-industrial ones)

Comment: good point I've added an couple of extra paragraphs to expand on this.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer for this awful question but I am still not clear that what and how one country will pay for some goods or services given by another country. If they are paying money for this then there are different currencies, and one country does not have the currency of another country, how they will arrange that currency?